# How to filter jobs with job names in Jenkin when using JSON REST API?

Tags: rest, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

We have Jenkin service with different jobs like Free Style Project jobs, Pipeline jobs etc. We are using JSON REST API `http://<<host>>:<<port>>/api/json?tree=jobs[*]{0,20}` for retrieving the jobs. Here We are looking to filter jobs based on the job class or based on the job name.

We could find references to filter the jobs with job name using XML REST APIs using `xpath`. Is there any way to achieve this using JSON APIs as well?

Thanks in advance.